# Image in ImageView not scaling properly

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView, ther are 2 Images for a particular imageview, but the problem is when i click it (the clicked image is bigger then the previous one). So the layout gets shifted upwards, i dont want layout to move upwards, i just want image to extend upwards.

```
// addnews button the 1st screen
    final ImageView addnewsback = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newslistback);
    ImageView addnews = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newslistbtn);
    addnews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            addnewsback.setImageResource(R.drawable.bgbig);
            vf.setDisplayedChild(0);                
        }
     });
```

[image]
[image]

The correct view should be,

[image]

Comment: Try adding layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the ImageView, also post some xml layout code.

Comment: Thanks but its not working..:(